# sns.set_style() command is not working on my code,please assist

Tags: python, matplotlib, numbers, seaborn

I tried using seaborn package in my code to scatter plot complex numbers, but I am not getting any output even after calling sns.set_style(). Please help.

````
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
import seaborn as sns
s = ([1 + 1j, 1 + 69j, 2 + 1j, 2 + 2j,4.5 - 6.4j])  # s is a list which contains all the complex numbers which r to be plotted
                  
            x = [x.real for x in s]
            y = [y.imag for y in s]
            plt.plot(x, y, 'o', c='red')
            plt.grid(True)
            plt.xlabel('Real number')
            plt.ylabel('Imaginary number')
            plt.title('Graph of given complex numbers')
            sns.set_style("dark")
            plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 1):

**please add the "sns.set_theme()" before #sns.set_style#**
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
import seaborn as sns
s = ([1 + 1j, 1 + 69j, 2 + 1j, 2 + 2j,4.5 - 6.4j])  # s is a list which contains all the complex numbers which r to be plotted

```
        x = [x.real for x in s]
        y = [y.imag for y in s]
        plt.plot(x, y, 'o', c='red')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.xlabel('Real number')
        plt.ylabel('Imaginary number')
        plt.title('Graph of given complex numbers')
        sns.set_theme() # to make style changable from defaults use this line of code befor using set_style
        sns.set_style("dark")
        plt.show()
```

**I hope this will now run**

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue here. What solved is moving where `sns.set_style()` is called.
`sns.set_style()` should be called before any `plt.` call.

Refactoring your code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
import seaborn as sns
s = ([1 + 1j, 1 + 69j, 2 + 1j, 2 + 2j,4.5 - 6.4j])  # s is a list which contains all the complex numbers which r to be plotted
                  
x = [x.real for x in s]
y = [y.imag for y in s]

sns.set_style("dark") # <--- Moving it here fixes it

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', c='red')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Real number')
plt.ylabel('Imaginary number')
plt.title('Graph of given complex numbers')

plt.show()
```

Below there are two plots, one setting up the style in the beginning and one in the end of the script.

[This is the plot using the `sns_set_style()` in the end of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoMbA.png)

[This is the plot  using the `sns_set_style()` in the beginning of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTJQA.png)